# In a Jquery button with icon: no space between the icon and text?

Tags: jquery, css

Thanks to jQuery UI, I can easily:

- having buttons with text only
- having buttons with text + icons
- having buttons with icon only

The problem is the font was too big so I added this css:

```
.ui-button .ui-button-text { 
    font-size:60%;
}
```

But now the problem is I didn't have any space between my icon and my text.

See here for demo (jsFiddle): http://jsfiddle.net/Rn9tg/71/

Is there any fix?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `&nbsp;`?

Comment: Yes but it is not very elegant :) I suppose something is wrong with my css >> .ui-button .ui-button-text { font-size:60%; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[UPDATE]**: Using left-margin rule does not work with icon only buttons. I replaced `left-margin` rule by a `text-indent` rule which seems to resolve the problem.

Add the following CSS rule

```
.ui-button-text:nth-child(2) {
    text-indent: 5px;
}​
```

This instruct that any `ui-button-text` class, which are the second child of a parent should have a left margin of 5px. In this case, the label always is the second child when it is preceded by the icon.

Learn more about nth-child pseudo selector at [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/).

[UPDATE]
Internet Explorer -specially older versions- does not support nth-chil pseudo selector correctly. In this case, you should use jquery to force IE to use an additional class.

Add the following class in a IE exclusive CSS file:

```
.button_left_margin_label {
    text-indent: 5px;
}
```

With jQuery, force IE to use the above class for labels which fallows an icon:

```
if IE {$('.ui-button-text:nth-child(2)').addClass('button_left_margin_label');}
```

Comment: This seems a good solution but unfortunately it doesn't work for the button with icon-only. I try with IE and Chrome without success. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/Rn9tg/96/

Comment: I see... so change "margin-left" by a "text-indent" rule. That's solve the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<a data-bind="click: greet, jqButton: { icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-gear' }}">&nbsp&nbsp&nbspTest</a>
```

You just need to add a left margin for the text, so that there is space in between the text and the icon. Check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rn9tg/92/).

Comment: Thanks for your response but I already try this solution. As you can see in your jsFiddle the button with icon only, we have too much space on the right. I would like a solution where every different buttons are correctly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Add a non-breaking space (or two) in front of your text. Like this **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Rn9tg/85/)**. So instead of just "Test", use `"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Test"`

Comment: I agree this solution works but I hope there is a more elegant solution than adding some spaces in front of the text...

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the demo that you have linked to I played with the code and get the solution for you. Here it is the CSS

```
.ui-button .ui-button-text { 
    font-size:60%;
    min-height: 13px;
    margin-left:5px;
}​
```

Give the margin to the text to left and you will see space is added.

I hope I helped you..

Comment: Thanks but as I responded to Anirvan, this solution didn't suit me because all buttons are not correctly formatted: in the button with icon only, there is too much space on the left.